# Get random itemids that a user did not buy

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I would like to output a list for each user with items that he has not bought. I already have this list, but it only outputs one list per user. I would like to expand this by adding as many items as a user has bought, for example, user 0 has bought three items so many different lists of items that have not been bought should be displayed

```
d = {'userid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
     'itemid': [715, 845, 98, 12324, 85, 715, 2112, 85, 2112, 852, 102]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.head())

all_items = set(df['itemid'])
# only need to remove the groupby statement
list_l = df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: random.sample(list(all_items.difference(set(x['itemid']))), 3)).tolist()
```

It looks like

```
0     [2112, 102, 85]
1     [85, 715, 102]
2     [2112, 852, 102]
3     [845, 852, 102]
4     [715, 98, 845]
```

I just want to remove the groupby statement, this should provide the desired output. Unfortunately, if I remove this, I get an error. Hence my question. How do I hand out items that a user has not bought and as often as he has bought items?
When I remove the groupby statement from this `df.apply(lambda x: random.sample(list(all_items.difference(set(x['itemid']))), 3))` I get `KeyError: 'itemid'`

---

Further explanation (
Not necessary if you already understood it before):

If I now make these comparisons `test.shape [0] == len (list_l)`
then these values ​​are different
What I would like to do, as often as a user has bought something, for example, user 0 has bought three times then items should be randomly selected for him three times that he has not bought, so the three lists should be different

What I want:

Note: x, y and z should stand for random numbers that the user did not buy.

```
0     [2112, 102, 85]
0     [x0, y0, z0] # x, y, z = different random items what the user not bought
0     [x1, y1, z1]
1     [85, 715, 102]
2     [2112, 852, 102]
2     [x2, y2, z2]
3     [845, 852, 102]
3     [x3, y3, z3]
4     [715, 98, 845]
4     [x4, y4, z4]
4     [x5, y5, z5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupby` statement is needed to perform operations within each user.
However, here's a possible solution to achieve your desired output

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from itertools import combinations

# create a list of non-bought items for each userid
user_not_bought = df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: list(all_items.difference(set(x['itemid'])))).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'not_bought'})
# merge the above dataframe with the main one
df_new = df.merge(user_not_bought, on='userid', how='left')
df_new['size'] = df_new.groupby('userid')['userid'].transform('size')
# extract randomly 3-element combinations of non-bought items
random.seed(123)
df_new.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: random.sample([list(e) for e in combinations(x['not_bought'][0], 3)], x['size'][0])).explode()

userid
0    [2112, 12324, 102]
0       [2112, 102, 85]
0    [2112, 12324, 852]
1       [102, 715, 852]
2      [2112, 102, 852]
2       [2112, 98, 852]
3      [98, 12324, 715]
3     [12324, 102, 852]
4      [12324, 845, 85]
4        [715, 845, 85]
4         [98, 845, 85]
dtype: object
```

This slightly complex solution ensures that the 3-element lists are always different within each `userid`. Also, the final results are lists instead of tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I run your code I get `NameError: name 'combinations' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to insert the imports. Check out my updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry about the circumstances. Now I get `KeyError: 0` or `KeyError: not_bought`. In the last line.

Comment: That's weird. Does your dataframe contain the following four columns? `userid`, `itemid`, `not_bought`, `size`

Comment: it contains this `userid itemid not_bought_x size not_bought_y not_bought_x not_bought_y not_bought_x not_bought_y` when I'm printing the df before the `random.seed(123)`

Comment: Ok, that's not good. You probably merged too many times. I'll edit my answer and I will create a dataframe, `df_new`, different from the original `df`. So re-run your code starting from the original `df` and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Excuse me. I keep receiving `KeyError: 0` in the last line

Comment: But the output of `df_new` before the `random.seed(123)` looks like `userid itemid not_bought size`

Comment: `df_new.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: random.sample([list(e) for e in combinations(x.loc[0, 'not_bought'], 3)], x.loc[0, 'size'])).explode()`   try to use this line as the last line

Comment: I am very sorry. It still does not work. Still the same mistake. I use google colab https://colab.research.google.com/ If that's important.

Comment: It works in Jupyter Notebook (don't know why), thank you very much for your time and support. I appreciate it very much.

Thank you again and apologize for the inconvenience and the fuss.

Comment: I was working with Jupyter Notebook too, but it seems strange that in colab it does not work.. Anyway, glad I could help :)

Comment: If you have the time and feel like it, could you please investigate why you get a `keyerror`? I have now performed it on another Jupyter and get this too. I'm sorry about it.